# Passing correct url but method still returns false... Any idea?

Tags: web-services, url

I verified url (http://portal.inhouse.dev/sites/promo/libray1/test.txt) but following method always returns false. It should return true per MS. Please suggest. I even tried it with http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/webservicestudio20 and still returns false and nulls for output fields.

```
public static string GetListItemIDByUrl(string url)
{
    sitedataservice.SiteData sd = new sitedataservice.SiteData();
    sd.Url = "http://basesmcdev2/sites/tester1/_vti_bin/sitedata.asmx";
    sd.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    string webId = string.Empty;
    string listId = string.Empty;
    string itemId = string.Empty;
    string bucketId = string.Empty;

    bool ret = sd.GetURLSegments(url, out webId, out bucketId, out listId, out itemId);

    return itemId;
}
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem when passing in the URL of a document. The only time I get a TRUE from GetURLSegments is when the URL I pass in is just "http://sharepoint2010". However in this case all IDs returned are null.
Has anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Context.

Your web service call has context of the web "tester1" but you're looking for a file in the web "promo". The web service can only get files for the web in which it currently has context.

Answer (score -1):

As I understand [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd931317%28office.12%29.aspx), you retrieves FALSE value because the item is located in the _vti_bin bin directory. This is virtual directory, not a list.

Comment: hmm. I am not reading like you are reading. hmm. All SP webservices under _vti_bit. The article says "he GetURLSegments operation is used to get the identifiers of a site, list, or list item depending on the specified URL." I AM LOST...

Comment: sorry, I did mistake... I thought that http://basesmcdev2/sites/tester1/_vti_bin/sitedata.asmx is a url of an item that you tries to get.

Comment: The item host (portal.inhouse.dev) and service host (basesmcdev2) are different. In http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd926682%28v=office.12%29.aspx article these hosts are the same.

Comment: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/webservicestudio20/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1394 this tools helps test web services. Same result though (false and nulls for values). Any SP Guru wants to jump in... or scared of Shark..

Comment: _vti_bin refers to web service calls. This answer is irrelevant.